# Is there a more compact way of notating two-note duplet division tremolos?

Tags: notation

Is there a really compact way of notating the following bar? I'm already using slash notehead on beats 2 and 3 to indicate "repeat the previous beat". But is there some way of writing just a pair of notes for the first beat and maybe somehow using tremolo notation to indicate the sextuplet? Or some other notation?

[image]

Comment: Many thanks in advance to Laurence Payne for his tip about the slash noteheads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was considering the **proposed** below, but can't say I've seen it in notation, but it might exist.
[image]

Comment: Your "proposed" notation looks the best to me, but I think I'd still have to explain it, as it's not notation you come across every day.

Comment: I would say definitely explain it! I've not seen it. But I think the train of thought makes sense in the above diagram.

Comment: I actually might have seen the proposed notation or a triplet equivalent in a Schubert work.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a few of them in succession, this might be acceptable.   But don't obsess on compacting to the extent of holding up reading with a 'wtf?' moment.

[image]